# Java: how to extract a number from a string where the number is a prefix?

Tags: java.util.scanner, string-parsing, number-formatting

I need to convert a string to a number. Problem is the string is user input and it may have units after it, and so the number portion is effectively a prefix. Here are some examples:

```
"8.1 in"
"3.0cm"
"90%"
"4'"
```

I'm having trouble extracting the number. NumberFormat.parse() looked promising. However, it has erratic behavior. It parses "4%" and "4x" into 4.0 just fine, but it throws a ParseException on "4'" and "4," (in Locale.US).

Scanner looked promising too, but it fails in the last 3 cases because, I gather, there is no delimiter between the numeric part and the unit. How can I reliably parse a float **up to** the first non-legit character, and do it right no matter the locale?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression. Something like this should do:

```
public class NumExtractor {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "HELLO32This is my small example ";
        String pattern = "\\D";
        System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(pattern, "")); 
    }
}
```

The code above would output:

```
32
```

Edit: I just realized that you wanted the output as a number. Here is a revision:

```
public class NumExtractor {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "HELLO32This is my small example ";
        String pattern = "\\D";
        double number = Double.parseDouble(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
        System.out.println(number); 
    }
}
```

Parse as a double in case the number has a decimal place in it.